# Cómo convierto un string con signo monetario a float en javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

```
$(".cuerpoInversiones").append(
  '<li class="">' +
  'Monto a invertir <strong class="float-right montoReserva">$' + monto + '</strong>' +
  '</li>'
);

var monto = $(".cuerpoInversiones .montoReserva").html();
```

Requiero convertir lo que viene de la etiqueta `.montoReserva` $1.000.000 a un float que quede solo 1000000 sin los puntos ni el signo $

Intenté con el `parseFloat` y me devuelve `NaN`.

Comment: @michael ayala, bienvenido a StackOverflow en español. Te recomendaría que te dieras una pasada por el [tour] para que conozcas un poco mejor cómo funciona la comunidad y de paso ganes tu primer medalla. También revisa este enlace para que veas como deberías armar tus preguntas: [mcve]

Comment: utiliza la función parseFloat(cadena)

Comment: ya utilice la funcion parseFloat y me devuelve Nan

Answer (score 4):

Para el caso que muestras, se puede aplicar la siguiente solución para reemplazar los caracteres que no necesitas.

```
var monto = $(".cuerpoInversiones .montoReserva").html();
monto = monto.replace(/\$|\./g, '')
```

Comment: Muchas gracias me sirvió tu respuesta